# Add new data to model sklearn: SGD

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I made models with sklearn, something like this:

clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log")

clf.fit(X, Y)

And then now I would like to add data to learn for this model, but with more important weight. I tried to use partial_fit with sample_weight bigger but not working. Maybe I don't use fit and partial_fit as good, sorry I'm beginner...

If someone know how to add new data I could be happy to know it :)

Thanks for help.

Comment: This is too vague, and possibly off-topic. Have you read the docs?

Comment: Yea I read the doc. It work with fit, but my problem is that I want to retrain the model with new data and this new data is more important than the first training.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_?

Comment: Because worked with fit, but when use partial_fit it's so wrong :)

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know how to explain.. When I train the first time with fit, results look correct, after I use partial_fit to add my new data (with weights) and then results become false

Comment: Hmm, okay. Do you think you could share your code and data, so that we can at least reproduce the messed up results aspect?

Comment: I think your assumption on the `sample_weight` parameter are wrong. I guess, you are doing the `sample_weight` only with `X` being new data. Could you show more code, please?

Comment: I use: partial_fit(new_X, new_Y, sample_weight=[10]*len(new_X)). What I need is that the new data is more important than the first learned

Comment: I will try to put more code, but I don't really have more ^^. But even, thanks for your help

Comment: You mentioned to have code with sample_weight. Please show that code. Or explain what you mean with add? running the notebook again with different data? Also it would be nice to explain what `not working` means.

Comment: Not working is when I calculate my error (what I expected - what I predicted) my results are worse than before.

Comment: The problem is I use FIT, it works quite good. Then I add more data to elarning, i use PARTIAL_FIT (as I wrote upper) to add data more important to learning. And the results are worse than after the first learning. Also I tried with only FIT and WARM_START but it's not working because sometimes I have only 1 classe to add.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it has other way to do a first learning and then add new data more important for the model? Keras?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do what you want is to call:

```
clf.partial_fit(X, Y, classes=np.unique(Y))
```

here you can also add the `sample_weight` vector with the weights for each sample.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit